# Mongoid - Fetch all subrelations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I currently have a problem with a system I am building. I have a model named `company` and a model named `team` (`user` is also available, but not important for this topic I think).
My `team` model includes the `user_ids`. But now I want to have a dynamic link of **all** users that are in teams to be available in the `company` model. How is this possible?

I searched the web, but "subrelations" is probably not the right wording for this.

**company.rb**

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  has_many :teams

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name

  belongs_to :admin, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :owned_teams
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Would be nice if anyone knows a solution for my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Mongoid` is not accepting `has many through` relations, I looked for a possible solution myself and found a little snippet that was helping myself graciously.

My **`company.rb`** looks like this now:

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy

  def users
    User.in(id: teams.map(&:user_id))
  end
end
```

So, to explain, the users method is searching for records of model `User` with the id's of all `teams` of the current company.

Here is a snippet to explain a little more:

```
# this should be the plural of your desired relation
def desired_relations
  # DesiredRelation: The model of the desired relation
  # through_relation: The relation that's the "through" method in ActiveRecord
  # desired_relation: The desired relation's id
  DesiredRelation.in(id: through_relation.map(&:desired_relation_id))
end
```